# How to add validators in angular table?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-forms, angular-validation

I am very new to angular.I have made an angular table where, upon clicking the table-data we can edit that data. Now I want to add validators to it, where if a user edits the field "carbohydrates"(for example) he/she will only be able to put numbers and if they put in any other character they will not be able to add it.

This is the link to the stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/implementing-edit-in-place-in-angular-xjw5sh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: pls have a look https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-table-editable?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches for adding Validators to your table.

1. If you use **reactive forms** [https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms][1] then you can simply add it in initialization time
   e.g.

   **public form = new FormGroup({
   name: new FormControl('John',
   {
   validators: [Validators.required],
   asyncValidators: [customAsyncValidator]
   }
   );**

or you also can do it **dynamically**:
**this.form.get('name').addValidators(Validators.required);
this.form.get('name').addAsyncValidators(customAsyncValidator);**

2)If you use **template-driven forms** you should create **@Directive** and import it to your module then you can used it in your template.

Comment: But can I do it in the span? Check the link

Comment: Sure, you can do it dynamically.  You don't need to do it in your template, add Validators in your ts file.
You can achieve it with function, 
for e.g. 
private addValidatorsToAllControls(): void {
   this.formGroup.controls.forEach((control: FormControl) => {
        control.addValidators(Validators.minLength(4));
        control.updateValueAndValidity();
    });
 }


Also don't forget to add error handling to your template,
for e.g.
<input type="text" formControlName="control">
 <div *ngIf=control.errors?.minlength>
    Name must be at least 4 characters long.
</div>